# How can css mask be positioned correctly in regard to its element bounds?

Tags: html, css

In this example, I want the transparent circular cutout to appear as a cut out half circle on the left (and vertical center) of the green box.

```css
div {
  background: green;
  mask: radial-gradient(20px, transparent 100%, black);
  mask-position: left center;
}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `gradient` to `50px at left center`

```css
div {
  background: green;
  mask: radial-gradient(50px at left center, transparent 100%, black);
}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
```